# Modifying Navigation Bar PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, navigation

New to coding: I've been trying to customize the "Rise Lite" template that Wordpress provides. What I want to be able to do is have a link on the far right of my navigation bar that will bring me back to the front page of my blog.

Currently I have three links on the far left.

Below is the code from my `header.php` file. Any suggestions?

I want the menu icon to be on the same plane and be the same format as the other buttons on the right.

```
<div id="mobilebgfix">
    <div class="mobile-bg-fix-img-wrap">
        <div class="mobile-bg-fix-img"></div>
    </div><!--/.mobile-bg-fix-img-wrap-->
    <div class="mobile-bg-fix-whole-site">
        <header id="home" class="header">
            <div id="main-nav" class="navbar navbar-inverse bs-  docs-nav" role="banner">
                <div class="container">
                    <nav class="navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse collapse" role="navigation" id="site-navigation">
                        <a class="screen-reader-text skip-link" href="#content"><?php _e( 'Skip to content',  'rise-lite' ); ?></a>
                        <?php wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location' => 'primary', 'container' => false, 'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-left responsive-nav main-nav-list', 'fallback_cb' => 'zerif_wp_page_menu')); ?>
                    </nav><!--/#site-navigation.navbar-collapse.bs-navbar-collapse.collapse-->
                </div><!--/.container-->
            </div><!--/#main-nav.navbar.navbar-inverse.bs-docs-nav-->
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and 
[How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  
SO is not a free coding or tutorial service. You have to **show us** the effort you have already made to solve your own problem.

Comment: css is what you need to learn